# How to make first row columns not clickable in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've made the app that way, when you click on current row you get a new form and there you can edit the item, anyway if I click on
[image]

Column Names:ID, Name, Country I get the new form again with first record to edit But I don't want to click on Column names and load edit form I only want that to happen when you click on first row and than to the end. So I've made it that way:

```
if (advancedDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0)
    {
        editRecord.ShowDialog();
    }
```

But I can't edit the first row now, any ideas how can I fix that?

Comment: In which event do you have that code? It seems that you need to check for null before trying to access the CurrentCell or CurrentRow

Comment: 0 is a valid index, so use `>=`

Comment: But that way when I click on the Columns I get the edit form again and I don't want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (advancedDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0)
```

Indexes start at 0. This condition ignores 0 and will only be valid when the index is greater than 0 (so starting at 1). If you case, because indexes start at 0, you need to use greater than or equal to 0 (`>=`).

**EDIT:**

To fix your issue to ignore the header cells:

```
    private void DataGridView_OnCellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && !(sender is DataGridViewHeaderCell))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("content cell was clicked");
        }
    }
```

Note that you must use the `CellClick` event handler.

Comment: But that way when I click on the Columns I get the edit form again and I don't want that.

Comment: You can check if the column index is > 0

Comment: And than I can't click on first row, read the question carefully.

Comment: So having (RowIndex >= 0 && ColumnIndex > 0) results in you not being able to select the first row, correct?

Comment: With rowindex >=0 I'm able to select first row but I'm able to select Columns Names Also and I don't want that. I want to select everything except column names in this picture u can see them ID, NAME, COUNTRY, NUMBER ,GENDER

Comment: Ah okay. This wasn't clear to me at first, I've updated my answer.